# How do I move redstone signals vertically (for a vertical sticky-piston door)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm trying to make a variation on the sticky-piston hidden door, in which two sticky pistons are activated by a pressure plate in a corridor to reveal either a hidden room, or a treasure chest, or trap, or anything else.

Stepping on the pressure plate would turn off the circuit so that one sticky piston pulls a block up into the ceiling, and the other pulls a block down into the floor. The resultant opening is one block wide by two blocks high.

The problem is I don't know how to wire the redstone vertically. A basic sticky-piston door is easy, as long as the blocks slide left or right but are harder to hide, which is why I want up-down activation. I just can't figure out the signal transmission.

I got half of it working - the down part - after I first posted this. It's getting the current to run up that is giving me trouble. I tried mirror-inverting my system for down to up and it didn't working

I have shredded Google trying to find a tutorial for vertical piston doors, but have failed to find anything. Can somebody give me a step-by-step or the link to a video tutorial in which this has already been done?

Thanks!

Comment: What difference between horizontal and vertical configurations is giving you trouble? Is it transferring redstone signal up/downwards? Or you have trouble "plugging" redstone into vertical pistons? Or you want to put the pressure plate right next to a door?

Comment: @OrcJMR - I got half of it working - the down part - after I posted this. It's getting the current to run up that was giving me trouble. I was trying to mirror-invert my system for down to up and it wasn't working, but I think I should be fine now with hedgehog1029's screenshots to guide me.

Comment: I edited the question to include the crux of your trouble (vertical wiring), so that should keep it from getting closed as "unclear" now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple. Have some screenshots.
This is the Redstone overview: (those are upside-down half slabs)

[image: vertical sticky piston door screenshot 1]

(also, the Redstone at the back leads to another pressure plate, but that's not important)
This is the door open:

[image: vertical sticky piston door screenshot 2]
And some more Redstone:

[image: vertical sticky piston door screenshot 3]
[image: vertical sticky piston door screenshot 4]

The two pressure plates and their respective Redstone:

[image: vertical sticky piston door screenshot 5]

If you need some more help contact me by replying!

Comment: No problem! If you need any help on anything else don't hesitate

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I streamlined your design a little. :P

Answer (score 1):

OK...

Here's what I've got (slightly more compact variation on the way hedgehog1029 has shown, above):

[image: screenshot]

The block beside the arrow has a redstone torch on the side of the next block under it that can't be seen from that angle, exactly as shown in hedgehog1029's third screenshot, above.

I have since moved the redstone torches and wiring around a bit so the door is flush with the wall.

I started with hedgehog1029's design so I had a functional model from which to base my revisions, then tweaked it as I went, and the above is my finished version, and without that help, I think it would have taken me a long time to figure it out, so thanks a ton!

:D

Comment: No problem! Redstone torches can be strange at times, so I understand your issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use redstone torches that are placed directly above eachother, because the one beneath the second redstone torch will turn the second redstone torch off, and the second redstone torch being off will turn the third one on, etc. But if you need it to be off at the top then you can add a NOT gate which will change the redstone it so that it is off at the top. You can also put a lever and make it so that when you flip the lever, everything is flipped and the redstone torch at the top turns from on to off or off to on. This process will make the redstone go vertically up so that you can connect the redstone to the bottom piston and the top piston at the same time.

NOT on the pressure plate:
[image]

ON the pressure plate:
[image]

More Redstone:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Have a question? Comment and I will answer!

Comment: I appreciate your feedback but the issue is resolved.