# Getting the signal from a floor pressure plate in the middle of a room

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have this contraption with a floor plate that causes certain changes in a wall couple of blocks away (ie, firing pistons, etc). The floor plate is on a stone floor, and I wouldn't like to mess up the floor with redstone wire - all the wiring must be under the floor, and the floor must all be at one level.

Well, I fail to understand this thing: how to get the signal down from the block on which the floor plate was pushed, without any holes around the floor. Thing is, you can't put a redstone torch upside down. If you could, then I'd put it on the bottom of the floor block and pull the redstone wire to wherever I need, and all of that in the underfloor area, so nothing of that is visible from outside. But since you can not, it seems that there is no other way than have a how just besides the floor block with plate, where to put the redstone wire.

Comment: Is the floor plate next to a wall or more than 1 block away from it?

Comment: Could this question possibly be of use to you? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/133411/how-do-i-move-redstone-signals-vertically-for-a-vertical-sticky-piston-door?rq=1

Comment: No walls around, then there wouldn't be this question - just have the wiring below that wall block and done. All floor must be level.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The pressure plate actually powers the block below it, so you can get the signal from below the block where the pressure plate is:

[image: pressure plate powering redstone beneath]

There is no need to have any holes on the floor.

Comment: Thanks, it never occoured to me that the floor block would wi-fi the signal to the redstone wire put on the block below.

Comment: @Passiday, any switches, buttons or plates will strongly power the block that they're on, and strongly powered blocks can pass a redstone current to any of the adjacent blocks.